# How do I get the parent directory path of a path in CMake?

Tags: cmake

How to find the parent directory in CMake ?

Assume that `${MYPROJECT_DIR}=/dir1/dir2/dir3/myproject/` and I want `${PARENT_DIR}=/dir1/dir2/dir3/`.

How to do that ?
`SET(PARENT_DIR ${MYPROJECT_DIR}/../)` doesn't seem to be the right syntax.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

For CMake 3.20 and newer, the recommended way is to use [cmake_path](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_path.html#get-parent-path) with a `PARENT_PATH` option:

```
cmake_path(GET MYPROJECT_DIR PARENT_PATH PARENT_DIR)
```

For older versions up to CMake 2.8.12, use the [get_filename_component](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/get_filename_component.html) command with the `DIRECTORY` option:

```
get_filename_component(PARENT_DIR ${MYPROJECT_DIR} DIRECTORY)
```

For versions of CMake older than 2.8.12, use the `PATH` option:

```
set (MYPROJECT_DIR /dir1/dir2/dir3/myproject/)
get_filename_component(PARENT_DIR ${MYPROJECT_DIR} PATH)
```

Comment: and if I want the parent of the parent? meaning  "/dir1/dir2/"?

Comment: @Takichiii : `get_filename_component(_parent, ${MYDIR}, DIRECTORY)` , and then `get_filename_component(_grandparent, ${_parent}, DIRECTORY)`

Answer (score 9):

As of CMake 3.20, you can use the [`cmake_path`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.20/command/cmake_path.html) command to get the parent directory of a given path:

> ```
> cmake_path(GET <path-var> PARENT_PATH <out-var>)
> ```

This command supersedes the `get_filename_component` command.

So, in your example, it would look like this:

```
cmake_path(GET MYPROJECT_DIR PARENT_PATH PARENT_DIR)
```

You can also check if the path has a parent directory component first:

```
cmake_path(HAS_PARENT_PATH MYPROJECT_DIR MyDir_HAS_PARENT)
if(MyDir_HAS_PARENT)
    cmake_path(GET MYPROJECT_DIR PARENT_PATH PARENT_DIR)
endif()
```

This doesn't actually check the filesystem to verify a valid path, but it is a really useful path manipulation command.

Answer (score 1):

For me it didn't work (at cmake 3.18).
I ended up using:

```
get_filename_component(VAR_PARENT ${MYPROJECT_DIR}/.. ABSOLUTE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the "CMakeLists.txt" example of [Sascha Kratky's above suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7036545/5595995):

Let's assume this is the project folder.

```
project
    |
    |_ src    
    |    |_ CMakeLists.txt 
    |    |_ test.cpp
    |
    |_ include   
         |_ add.hpp
```

and then "CMakeLists.txt" would be

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14.0)
set(project_name Simple)
project(${project_name})

set( cur_path ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} )
cmake_path(GET cur_path PARENT_PATH parent_path)
set( includes ${parent_path}/include )

include_directories( ${includes} )

set( sources ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test.cpp )
add_executable( ${project_name} ${sources} )
```